# Called contract function via txn builder; no transaction shows up on Etherscan at that contract address, but Events do. Did I call it successfully?

Tags: transactions

I used a Safe on Arbitrum ("Safe") to call the `release` function on a contract ("contract") via the transaction builder.

I *think* I did this successfully, but it doesn't show up on-chain.

As an example, my friend, using a different EOA address, and calling a different contract, was able to see his `release` transaction on-chain at his (different) contract address.

But when you check my contract address, you don't see any transactions on-chain.

However, you CAN see in the `Events` tab of the contract that it looks like the function was called.

I just want to make sure this is all normal, and ideally I'd love to understand why this happens.

In summary:

- if using an EOA to call `release` on a contract, the `release` function call shows up on-chain
- if using a Gnosis multisig to call `release` on a contract, the `release` function does NOT show up on chain. The only thing that shows up on Etherscan is one of my EOA's calling a function on my Gnosis multisig, but NOT my EOAs or my multisig calling `release` on the contract.

TL;DR - Did I successfully call `Release` on the contract using my Safe? The transaction looks fine in Safe, but nothing shows up on the Transactions page on Etherscan at that contract address.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it would be a gasless transaction with offchain signing.